# awk: append line to previous line if there are fewer than 5 columns

Tags: bash, awk

I have a messy input file which has unexpected line breaks. The file it tab delimited. Since some of the columns are text data, I figured awk was a good bet but I'm not well versed in it.

Though each line is supposed to have N columns, there are incorrect line breaks and many rows have fewer columns. Here's a dummy example,

```
a1  a2  a3  a4  a5
b1  b2  b3  b4  b5
c1  c2  c3
c4  c5
d1  d2  d3
d4
d5
e1  e2  e3  e4  e5
```

[ Note that there are never fewer than 3 columns when a row actually begins. You never have a break like this, `f1  f2 \n f3  f4  f5` ]

So I want to remove the incorrect line breaks and have it looks like this, where each row has 5 columns,

```
a1 a2 a3 a4 a5
b1 b2 b3 b4 b5
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
d1 d2 d3 d4 d5
e1 e2 e3 e4 e5
```

So I need a way to append a line to the previous line if it has fewer than 3 columns. Or to append a line to the next line and update NF, so that you repeatedly append until there are 5 columns.
I tried editing "awk 'NF<4{printf "%s", $0;next}1' file" to append to the previous line but that doesn't work. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with `gawk`

```
awk -v RS='[ \n]+' 'ORS=NR%5?FS:"\n"' file

a1 b1 c1 d1 e1
a2 b2 c2 d2 e2
a3 b3 c3 d3 e3
a4 b4 c4 d4 e4
a5 b5 c5 d5 e5
```

assumes the data is space delimited set the record separator to space or newline to tokenize all fields as records, `NR` counts the records and after each 5th record (where `NR/5` becomes zero) insert a newline by setting the output record separator `ORS`, otherwise use field separator `FS` between fields, which is space by default.

Comment: Although slightly more complex, with large input sets this solution will perform much better than the `xargs` solution. If the input is tab-delimited, as in the OP's case, use `'[\t\n]'` instead of `[ \n]+`.

Answer (score 3):

Using `xargs` :

**Input**

```
$ cat file
a1  a2  a3  a4  a5
b1  b2  b3  b4  b5
c1  c2  c3
c4  c5
d1  d2  d3
d4
d5
e1  e2  e3  e4  e5
```

**Output**

```
$ xargs -n 5 < file
a1 a2 a3 a4 a5
b1 b2 b3 b4 b5
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
d1 d2 d3 d4 d5
e1 e2 e3 e4 e5
```

Comment: You can't beat the conceptual simplicity of this solution, but note that a child process - `/bin/echo` - is created for every 5 input fields, which can become an issue with large input files.
Also note that `xargs` will "eat" single `\ ` instances in the input; e.g., `echo 'a\b' | xargs` yields `ab`.

Comment: @mklement0: Yes true, I agree